# Google Sheets Double Sheet Reference

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I have two sheets in the same workbook. I need to pull data to the first based off information in both.

This is my current format I'm working on:

```
=VLOOKUP(DATEVALUE(TEXT(E2,"mm/dd/yyyy")),VIX!A2,I2)
```

I need it to do this basically: If the date in E2 matches the date in A2 on sheet "VIX" then return the data in cell I2 on sheet "VIX"

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 2):

you miss a comma:

```
=VLOOKUP(DATEVALUE(TEXT(E2, "mm/dd/yyyy")), VIX!A2, I2, )
```

and I2 is hopefully = 1

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the [IF statement](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en)?

```
=IF(DATEVALUE(TEXT(E2,"mm/dd/yyyy")) = 'VIX'!A2, 'VIX'!I2, "E2 does not match VIX I2")
```